# Assign the same value to multiple keys in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I want my dictionary to look like this:

```
{'A': {('B','C'): 'D'}}
```

The code I'm using currently doesn't seem to work to achieve this result.

```
dict1 = {}
with open('foo.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
        for key in ['B','C']:
            dict1.setdefault(row['A'], {}).update({row[key]: row['D']})
```

Currently, I'm getting a result like this:

```
{'A': {'B': 'D','C': 'D'}}
```

Basically, I want B & C to be represented as the key with D as its value.

What am I doing wrong here? Can someone help me correct this code?

Comment: `{'B','C': 'D'}` what is that supposed to mean?

Comment: Its a dictionary within a dictionary. So A is the first key with values {'B','C':'D'}. This value is itself a dictionary with keys 'B','C' and a value 'D'. Does that make sense @njzk2?

Comment: That's what your result is, it is correct.  Dictionary with keys B and C, both of which have value D.

Comment: You can have multiple values for one key i.e., a list of values but if you'll give the same value to multiple keys, then that will be displayed the way you are getting your output and never the way how you are wanting it to be as the terms 'key' 'value' in itself mean that we are going to refer to a key's value and not the other way round (i mean you can, but i hope you get my point). 
And @EoinS said it right, that your result is correct indeed.!!

Comment: it doesn't really. a dictionary needs to have one key and one value for each entry. You can use tuples as keys, but then that means that you need the complete tuple to access the value. (you can't access `D` with just `B` or just `C`)

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. I'm a newbie and I just got confused. I appreciate the explanation it makes no sense for me to do this. Thank god for StackOverflow! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put both items right where you want them, in the tuple:

```
dict1 = {}
with open('foo.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for row in reader:
         dict1.setdefault(row['A'], {}).update({(row['B'], row['C']): row['D']})
    #                                               ^         ^
```